# JSON string from NSMutableDictionary -

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary

I wanted to generate a JSON string of the following format:

```
{
    "test": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "gte": "100"
    }
}
```

When I executed the following lines of code:

```
                NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [tempArray addObject:tempDict];
                [tempArray addObject:subDict];

                [dict setObject:tempArray forKey:@"test"];
```

I retrieved this JSON string.

```
{
    "test": [{
        "currency": "USD"
    }, {
        "gte": "100"
    }]
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: An array is not a dictionary, a dictionary is not an array. Read the JSON specification at json.org and the documentation of the `NSJSONSerialization` class. The mistake is entirely obvious.

Comment: gte:100 should be another key value pair in tempDict, not as another subDict.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it like this instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[tempDict setObject: @"USD" forKey: @"Currency"];
[tempDict setObject: @"100" forKey: @"gte"];

[dict setObject:tempDict forKey:@"test"];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your current try you are adding array of dictionary to dictionary so its display like

```
{"test":[{"currency":"USD"},{"gte":"100"}]}
```

You need to add dictionary,
Try Following,

```
 NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            tempDict,
                            subDict,
                            nil];
    NSDictionary *final=@{@"test": dict};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [@{} mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [@{} mutableCopy];
tempDic[@"currency"] = @"USD";
tempDic[@"gte"] = @"100";
[dic setObject:dic forKey:@"test"];
```

Modern Objective-C style..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
NSDictionary *yourDict = @{@"test": @{@"currency": @"USD",@"gte": @"100"}};
```